# Why are strings parsed through BeatifulSoup returned as None?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can't find why my 2 variables are returning "None" while they are defined in the loops.

Even The print ".span.text.find("France"))" doesn't work. I guess my two loops are not executed. I do not know why.

I also doubt that the problem comes from the soup. Indeed, sometimes it works. sometimes not where I do not touch the code.

```
#IMPORT DES LIBRAIRIRES
import bs4
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date


#VARIABLES                              
date_jour = date.today()
URL ="https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6"

# Chrome session USING SELENIUM
#driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/33769/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
#driver.get(URL)
#driver.implicitly_wait(100)
#soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

#USING REQUESTS
req = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")


nb_infected = None
nb_deaths = None

#Infected Cases France
for span in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'flex-fluid list-item-content overflow-hidden'})[:12]:
    if span.text.find("France")!= -1:
        nb_infected = span.text.replace('\n\n','')
        nb_infected = nb_infected.replace('\xa0','')
        nb_infected = nb_infected.replace('France','')
        print("OKKKKKK")
    else:
        print("NOT OK")
    print(span.text.find('France')) # NOT EXECUTED... WHY ???


#Deaths France
for span in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'flex-fluid list-item-content overflow-hidden'})[420:480]:
    if span.text.find("France")!= -1:
        nb_deaths = span.text.replace('\n\n','')
        nb_deaths = nb_deaths.replace('\xa0','')
        nb_deaths = nb_deaths.replace('deaths\nFrance','')

print("To conclude, in France, there are " + str(nb_infected) + " infected individuals and " + str(nb_deaths) + " deaths" )
#ONLY THIS LAST FINE WORKS....
```

Comment: Please, do NOT provide your code as image. Provide your code as text, instead. Thanks.

Comment: Done ! Sorry ...

Comment: Code doesn't match with image

Answer (score 1):

There is a different endpoint that is constantly providing updated data. You can hit that with an xhr instead and parse the json returned. Seems you can use the data if for educational purposes which I think this qualifies as.

```
import requests

headers = {
   'Referer': 'https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}

r = requests.get('https://services9.arcgis.com/N9p5hsImWXAccRNI/arcgis/rest/services/Nc2JKvYFoAEOFCG5JSI6/FeatureServer/2/query?f=json&where=Recovered%3C%3E0&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&orderByFields=Recovered%20desc&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=250&cacheHint=true', headers=headers, verify=False)
data = r.json()['features']
france = [i['attributes'] for i in data if i['attributes']['Country_Region'] == 'France']
if france:
    print(france)
    print("To conclude, in France, there are " + f'{france[0]["Confirmed"]:,}' + " infected individuals and " + f'{france[0]["Deaths"]:,}' + " deaths" )
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer ! I used selenium to create the page from the driver and used time.sleep(5) to be sure to page displayed correctly ! Here is the code :

```
#IMPORT DES LIBRAIRIRES
import bs4
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date


#VARIABLES                              
date_jour = date.today()
URL ="https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6"


# Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/33769/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
time.sleep(5)

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

nb_infected = None
nb_deaths = None

#Infected Cases France
for span in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'flex-fluid list-item-content overflow-hidden'})[:12]:
    if span.text.find("France")!= -1:
        nb_infected = span.text.replace('\n\n','')
        nb_infected = nb_infected.replace('\xa0','')
        nb_infected = nb_infected.replace('France','')

#Deaths France
for span in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'flex-fluid list-item-content overflow-hidden'})[420:480]:
    if span.text.find("France")!= -1:
        nb_deaths = span.text.replace('\n\n','')
        nb_deaths = nb_deaths.replace('\xa0','')
        nb_deaths = nb_deaths.replace('deaths\nFrance','')

print("To conclude, in France, there are " + str(nb_infected) + " infected individuals and " + str(nb_deaths) + " deaths" )
```